# Por que usar Bytes ao invés de usar Image? Qual a melhor prática?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, imagem

Gostaria de saber por que usar o tipo de dado `Bytes` ao invés de usar o próprio `Image`. Se o banco de dados SQL Server possuí o tipo de dado Image, logo deverá ser mais fácil e prático a inserção no modo `Image` certo?

Gostaria de um exemplo de como pegar a imagem do formulário e salvar em um banco de dados SQL Server, e depois recupera-la para uma View.

Comment: Vejo aí 2 perguntas, uma boa e uma imprópria.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vejo alguns motivos para isso. O primeiro deles é que o tipo de dados `Image` será removido em alguma versão futura do SQL Server.[(MSDN) Os tipos de dados ntext, text e image serão removidos em uma versão futura do Microsoft SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187993.aspx)

O `Image` da biblioteca `System.Drawing` não é equivalente ao campo `Image` do Sql Server, e não fizeram nenhum "mapeamento" pra ele. Concordo que até ficaria mais simples, porém, não é difícil converter uma imagem em uma array de bytes:

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    imageIn.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
    return  ms.ToArray();
}
```

`System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif` você substitui por sei lá qual formato sua imagem for. [(MSDN) Formatos de Imagem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Retirei este código do StackOverflow.com (pergunta 17352061)

Do mais a mais, este campo `image` nada mais contém do que `Dados binários do comprimento variável de 0 a 2^31-1 (2.147.483.647) bytes.`, como cita o primeiro link do msdn que mandei.

Espero ter ajudado. Quanto ao exemplo, dê uma procurada no google, é bem fácil encontrar.

Comment: Outro motivo é que podemos fazer upload e salvar arquivos de qualquer tipo, que não sejam necessariamente imagens.

Comment: Ótima resposta! Saberia me explicar como limitar para receber arquivos de tal extensão? Pois na minha page eu quero receber apenas .jpeg (.jpg é a mesma coisa creio eu) e .png

Comment: @LuizNegrini receber arquivos que tenham a extensão .jpg, ou receber apenas arquivos de imagem? Porque é possível renomear um arquivo .pdf (por ex.) para .jpg, e seu site aceitaria como se fosse uma imagem.

Comment: @woliveirajr seria receber somente imagem e somente com estas extensões.

Comment: @LuizNegrini você poderia fazer uma nova pergunta sobre isto, ficaria legal. Como restringir para que o upload seja feito apenas com determinadas extensões, e como determinar que o conteúdo é um arquivo jpeg válido

Comment: @woliveirajr ok, valeu!

Comment: Nada do que você determinar seria pelo BD. Extensão do arquivo você faz pelo cliente, se ele é um jpeg válido só depois de concluir o upload você poderá processar o arquivo de alguma maneira e novamente é algo que a aplicação poderia fazer.

Answer (score 0):

Outra solução é não guardar blobs na base de dados de maneira alguma. Isso é especialmente bom para performance quando você faz upload/donwload de arquivos grandes. Por experiência tenho visto que é muito mais eficiente guardar os arquivos num repositório e apenas salvar na base de dados um link/path para ele.

Comment: O SQL Server tem um tipo de dados para isso.

Comment: Todos os SGBD tem, até para que não fiquem com "menos funcionalidades que seus concorrentes" mas ter a funcionalidade não significa que você precise usa-la ou que ela fornece a melhor solução. Certamente 100% das funcionalidades não oferecem a melhor prática em 100% dos cenários. Este é um deles.

Comment: Acredito que hoje em dia os principais o façam. O SQL Server nem sempre o fez. Nunca usei e posso estar enganado, mas Uma das coisas que o SQL Server dá é o backup integrado destes ficheiros com o resto da BD. Se não me engano, nas últimas versões até dá acesso "direto" ao ficheiro. Só vejo vantagens. Ou estou enganado?

Comment: A versão 2012 trouxe os FileTables que poderiam ser usados neste caso mas ainda não testei a performance. De qualquer modo qual seria a vantagem de manter essas imagens na base num caso hipotético de você ter 1TB de dados e 2TB de imagens?

Comment: Integridade referencial. Gestão de backups. Consistência de backups.